# if/else variable declaration and object does not exist in current context error

Tags: c#, .net, conditional-statements

I have the following code which declares two variables and then executes a query. The variables will be created no matter what, so I am surprised to be getting an `object does not exist in current context error` when the query is about to execute. How can I do something like this? It has happened several times. I also tries to use an if/else statement in the declaration of the variable but that has not worked. (Then I get the error `invalid expression if`) What do I need to say for this to work?

```
        if (from_date == null) {
           var from_date_choose = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30);
        } else { 
            var from_date_choose = from_date;
        }

        if (to_date == null) {
           var to_date_choose = DateTime.Today;
        } else {
            var to_date_choose = to_date;
        }

        var voyages = db.Voyages
       .Where(v => v.ArrivalDatetime >= from_date_choose)
       .Where(v => v.ArrivalDatetime <= to_date_choose);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Modify the code like this, otherwise your variables exist only in local scope. You also need to use `from_date.Value` and `to_date.Value` (I assume these are of type `Nullable<DateTime>`):

```
DateTime from_date_choose;
if (from_date == null) {
   from_date_choose = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30);
} else { 
    from_date_choose = from_date.Value;
}

DateTime to_date_choose;
if (to_date == null) {
   to_date_choose = DateTime.Today;
} else {
    to_date_choose = to_date.Value;
}

var voyages = db.Voyages
.Where(v => v.ArrivalDatetime >= from_date_choose)
.Where(v => v.ArrivalDatetime <= to_date_choose);
```

You may also use the ternary operator, eg.:

```
DateTime from_date_choose = from_date == null ? DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30) : from_date.Value;
```

Or as Jeppe Stig Nielsen suggested use coalesce operator, eg:

```
DateTime from_date_choose = from_date ?? DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30);
```

Comment: Even better than the `?:` operator, this is a typical use for the null coalescing operator `??`, so `DateTime from_date_choose = from_date ?? DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30);`.

Answer (score 5):

You've declared `from_date_choose` and `to_date_choose` in local variable scope.  You can't access them where you've declared `voyages`.

You need to declare `from_date_choose` and `to_date_choose` in the same scope as `voyages`, for example:

```
DateTime from_date_choose;
if (from_date == null) {
   from_date_choose = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30);
} else { 
    from_date_choose = from_date;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

from_date_choose and from_date_choose are declared inside the scope of your if statements.
The where clause doesn't have them in scope. Your best best is to declare them at the top and then assign to them later on. I would declare them at the top and set them to whatever you would use as a default and then override it if the chosen value isn't null like this

```
    DateTime from_date_choose = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30);
    DateTime to_date_choose = DateTime.Today;

    if (from_date != null) {
       var from_date_choose = from_date;
    }

    if (to_date != null) {
        var to_date_choose = to_date;
    }

    var voyages = db.Voyages
   .Where(v => v.ArrivalDatetime >= from_date_choose)
   .Where(v => v.ArrivalDatetime <= to_date_choose);
```

Answer (score 3):

What you declare within an if statement is accessible within that if statement scope only. **This is called [scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx) of variable**. change your method like this

```
  DateTime from_date_choose;
  DateTime to_date_choose;

  if (from_date == null) {
       from_date_choose = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30);
    } else { 
       from_date_choose = from_date;
    }

    if (to_date == null) {
       to_date_choose = DateTime.Today;
    } else {
       to_date_choose = to_date;
    }

    var voyages = db.Voyages
   .Where(v => v.ArrivalDatetime >= from_date_choose)
   .Where(v => v.ArrivalDatetime <= to_date_choose);
```