# Why can't I execute the Method here in C#

Tags: c#, while-loop

```cs
if (titleGiven)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a title:");
    title = Console.ReadLine(); 
    Post firstPost = new Post(title, username, isPublic);
}
else
{
    Post firstPost = new Post();
}
    
while (end)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to check the information about the post? Yes|No");
    checkPost = Console.ReadLine(); 
    if (checkPost == "yes")
    {
        firstPost.ShowInfo(); 
    }
                        
}
```

So basically when I enter a title, a new object of the class Post is being made. This class has a method called ShowInfo() which displays the ID, the title, the user who posted the post etc.  So in my while I check if the user wants to check the post info, if that is the case the ShowInfo Method of the class Post should show up. But it doesn't let me use the Method, because there is no such thing as a "firstPost" in this context.

Comment: scope. things declare withing `{}` stay between `{}`. Move the variable decalrariton outside of the if else. only do the assgnment there.

Comment: I will recommend giving [ask] and [mre] a try. And always include the error message you are getting in your search and in your question. here "CS0103" is the keyword that will give you every tool needed to solve the issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable does not exist in the current context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233630/variable-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context)

Comment: And [if/else variable declaration and object does not exist in current context error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885046/if-else-variable-declaration-and-object-does-not-exist-in-current-context-error/17885103).

Comment: What happens in brackets stays in brackets :)

Answer (score 1):

This is all about scopes. The easiest way in your example to understand the problem is that: scope of variable is limited by braces {} where variable is defined.

So your variable is in only in `if` and corresponding `else` scope. In order for it to be visible in other "sub-scopes", you need to declare it outside `if`:

```
Post firstPost;
if (titleGiven)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a title:");
    title = Console.ReadLine(); 
    firstPost = new Post(title, username, isPublic);
}
else
{
    firstPost = new Post(); 
}
```

Comment: There seems to be no point in assigning null to firstPost if you are guaranteed to be setting it in the next if statement. Its a readability thing of course but I always feel that assigning it a value suggests the value you assign might be used in some context (eg it suggests to me there might be times when firstPost is not assigned to later).

Comment: @Chris Good point, I just did it so there is no error such as "use of unassigned variable", but I just checked and this will not cause the error :) thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to declare first post outside of the if/else statements, and then set them within the if/else statements:

```
Post firstPost = default;
if (titleGiven)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a title:");
                title = Console.ReadLine(); 
                firstPost = new Post(title, username, isPublic);
            }
            else
            {
                firstPost = new Post(); 
            }

            while(end)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Do you want to check the information about the post? Yes|No");
                checkPost = Console.ReadLine(); 
                if (checkPost == "yes")
                {
                    firstPost.ShowInfo(); 
                }
                    
            }
```

The reason why has to do with the scope of the variable that you're declaring. See more here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444020/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-an-if-statement#:~:text=variable%20'a'%20can%20be%20accessed,have%20declare%20variable%20'a'.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444020/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-an-if-statement#:%7E:text=variable%20%27a%27%20can%20be%20accessed,have%20declare%20variable%20%27a%27.)

Answer (score 0):

firstPost is unknown to the while loop because it is out of scope

I suggest doing it like this (I did not test this):

```
Post firstPost;
if (titleGiven)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a title:");
    title = Console.ReadLine();
    firstPost = new Post(title, username, isPublic);
}
else
{
    firstPost = new Post();
}

while (end)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to check the information about the post? Yes|No");
    checkPost = Console.ReadLine();
    if (checkPost == "yes")
    {
        firstPost.ShowInfo();
    }

}
```